# How can I evaluate performances of a lockless queue?

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, lockless

I have implemented a lockless queue using the hazard pointer methodology explained in http://www.research.ibm.com/people/m/michael/ieeetpds-2004.pdf using GCC CAS instructions for the implementation and pthread local storage for thread local structures.
I'm now trying to evaluate the performance of the code I have written, in particular I'm trying to do a comparison between this implementation and the one that uses locks (pthread mutexes) to protect the queue.
I'm asking this question here because I tried comparing it with the "locked" queue and I found that this has better performances with respect to the lockless implementation. The only test I tried is creating 4 thread on a 4-core x86_64 machine doing 10.000.000 random operations on the queue and it it significantly faster than the lockless version.

I want to know if you can suggest me an approach to follow, i.e. what kind of operation I have to test on the queue and what kind of tool I can use to see where my lockless code is wasting its time.

I also want to understand if it is possible that the performance are worse for the lockless queue just because 4 threads are not enough to see a major improvement...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First point: lock-free programming doesn't necessarily improve speed. Lock-free programming (when done correctly) guarantees forward progress. When you use locks, it's possible for one thread to crash (e.g., go into an infinite loop) while holding a mutex. When/if that happens, no other thread waiting on that mutex can make any more progress. If that mutex is central to normal operation, you may easily have to restart the entire process before any more work can be done at all. With lock-free programming, no such circumstance can arise. Other threads can make forward progress, regardless of what happens in any one thread<sup>1</sup>.

That said, yes, one of the things you *hope* for is often better performance -- but to see it, you'll probably need more than four threads. Somewhere in the range of dozens to hundreds of threads would give your lock-free code a much better chance of showing improved performance over a lock-based queue. To really do a lot of good, however, you not only need more threads, but more cores as well -- at least based on what I've seen so far, with four cores and well-written code, there's unlikely to be enough contention over a lock for lock-free programming to show much (if any) performance benefit.

Bottom line: More threads (at least a couple dozen) will improve the chances of the lock-free queue showing a performance benefit, but with only four cores, it won't be terribly surprising if the lock-based queue still keeps up. If you add enough threads and cores, it becomes almost inevitable that the lock-free version will win. The exact number of threads and cores necessary is hard to predict, but you should be thinking in terms of dozens at a minimum.

---

<sup>1</sup> At least with respect to something like a mutex. Something like a fork-bomb that just ate all the system resources might be able to deprive the other threads of enough resources to get anything done -- but some care with things like quotas can usually prevent that as well.

Answer (score 1):

The question is really to what workloads you are optimizing for. If congestion is rare, lock structures on modern OS are probably not too bad. They mainly use CAS instructions under the hood as long as they are on the fast path. Since these are quite optimized out it will be difficult to beat them with your own code.

Our own implementation can only win substantially for the congested part. Just random operations on the queue (you are not too precise in your question) will probably not do this if the average queue length is much longer than the number of threads that hack on it in parallel. So you must ensure that the queue is short, perhaps by introducing a bias about the random operation that is chosen if the queue is too long or too short. Then I would also charge the system with at least twice as much threads than there are cores. This would ensure that wait times (for memory) don't play in favor of the lock version.

Comment: I know that modern OS locks are not too bad and I also know that my question wasn't sufficiently precise. I had just tried to to random enqueue/dequeue where every thread tries to stress the queue doing this operations in a while(1) after which they terminate. I also know that four cores are not enough, I'm just trying to understand if I can SEE a speedup. Your answer was useful, I will try what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The best way in my opinion is to identify hotspots in your application with locks
by profiling the code.Introduce the lockless mechanism and measure the same again.
As mentioned already by other posters, there may not be a significant improvement
at lower scale (number of threads, application scale, number of cores) but you might
see throughput improvements as you scale up the system.This is because deadlock
situations have been eliminated and threads are always making forward progress.

Another way of looking at an advantage with lockless schemes are that to some
extent one decouples system state from application performance because there
is no kernel/scheduler involvement and much of the code is userland except
for CAS which is a hw instruction.

With locks that are heavily contended, threads block and are scheduled once
locks are obtained which basically means they are placed at the end of the run
queue (for a specific prio level).Inadvertently this links the application to system
state and response time for the app now depends on the run queue length.

Just my 2 cents.